# I'm trying to catch the input of the swiped card but I'm stuck using C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, events, credit-card

I am using a test card and this is the output after I swiped the card and it is ok

[image]

But when I'm trying to get the data of the swiped through prompting it to messagebox this will be the output

[image]

How can I fix this? I am expecting the output same as the first image, and it will also be the message of the messagebox

Here is my code:

```
private void CreditCardProcessor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            KeyPreview = true;
            KeyPress += CreditCardProcessor_KeyPress;
        }
    private bool inputToLabel = true;
        private void CreditCardProcessor_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (inputToLabel)
            {
                label13.Text = label13.Text + e.KeyChar;
                e.Handled = true;

            }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }

            MessageBox.Show(label13.Text);
        }
```

In short I want to run a function after swiping the card, and use its data to be use in my function. :)

Comment: Consider removing all mentioning of credit card from sample and shorten it to something like `var keyChar='a';MessageBox.Show("foo"+keyChar);`... There is no chance to answer the question without information what is in e.KeyChar and what you xpect to be there.

Comment: when using break point to e.keychar, i noticed it loops, so the first loop is %, second % third 1 and etc.. and produce the %%1000..etc

Comment: What I expect is that your card reader emulates a keyboard and sends keystrokes when a card is swiped, and a `Enter` key is sent at the end, so you could just used a `TextBox` and detect the `Enter` key being pressed.

Comment: @AlvinWong, but I want to happen is that in a function after swiping the card and get that data from it and run a certain function

Comment: Any ideas? I just want to get the data and run a certain function :( please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to be more specific with your question. From the looks of things your card scanner is operating through the keyboard buffer. (Many card scanners operate this way) This means that every character of the strip is received as a character which is why you can capture this `OnKeyPress`.

If you're wondering why you're only seeing one character at a time it is exactly because you're raising a message box with each character received. If you want to know when you can call a function with the whole card info using that code what you'll need is something like:

```
private bool inputToLabel = true;
private StringBuilder cardData = new StringBuilder();
private void CreditCardProcessor_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!inputToLabel)
            return;

        if (e.KeyChar == '\r')
        {
            MessageBox.Show(cardData.ToString()); // Call your method here.
        }
        else
        {
            cardData.Append(e.KeyChar);
            //label13.Text = label13.Text + e.KeyChar;
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Caveat: This is assuming that the card reader library is configured to terminate a card read with carriage return. (\r) You'll need to read up, or experiment with it for settings as to whether it can/does send a terminating character to know when the card read is complete. Failing that you can watch the output string for patterns. (I.e. when the captured string ends with "??") Though this is less optimal.